# How to send a complex objects to MVC .net framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I know there are similar questions, but mine is just different enough to warrant me asking.

I'm trying to send a complex object via ajax to a .net MVC backend.

the receiving call is this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult SaveLenderMemberSettings(List<AssignmentFeeRule> AssignmentFeeRules)
{
    return Json(AssignmentFeeRules);
}

....

public class AssignmentFeeRule
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public DateTime CutOffTimeBuy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CutOffTimeSell { get; set; }
    public int MinimumDaysToCloseBuy { get; set; }
    public int MinimumDaysToCloseSell { get; set; }
    public int OffsetDaysBuy { get; set; }
    public int OffsetDaysSell { get; set; }
}
```

The call is getting invoked properly, but when I try and send the object, it's sent as the following:

```
AssignmentFeeRules[0][Currency]:AZN
AssignmentFeeRules[0][MinimumDaysToCloseBuy]:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0][MinimumDaysToCloseSell]:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0][OffsetDaysSell]:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0][OffsetDaysBuy]:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0][CutOffTimeBuy]:01:00
AssignmentFeeRules[0][CutOffTimeSell]:14:01
```

As a result of this code:

```
var assignmentFeeRule = {
    Currency:$(tds[0]).find('select, input').val(),
    MinimumDaysToCloseBuy:$(tds[1]).find('select, input').val(),
    MinimumDaysToCloseSel":$(tds[2]).find('select, input').val(),
    OffsetDaysSell:$(tds[3]).find('select, input').val(),
    OffsetDaysBuy:$(tds[4]).find('select, input').val(),
    CutOffTimeBuy:$(tds[5]).find('select, input').val(),
    CutOffTimeSell:$(tds[6]).find('select, input').val()
};

assignmentFeeRules[rowCount - 1] = assignmentFeeRule

var data = {
AssignmentFeeRules : assignmentFeeRules
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    data: data
}).done(function (data) {
    console.dir(data);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.dir(error);
});
```

but I figured out that MVC needs it to be like this:

```
AssignmentFeeRules[0].Currency:AZN
AssignmentFeeRules[0].MinimumDaysToCloseBuy:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0].MinimumDaysToCloseSell:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0].OffsetDaysSell:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0].OffsetDaysBuy:2
AssignmentFeeRules[0].CutOffTimeBuy:01:00
AssignmentFeeRules[0].CutOffTimeSell:14:01
```

So far all my searches for an answer havn't turned up anything.

So basically, the bottom line is, how do I get this from an associative array a json object?

Comment: What is the method `Json(AssignmentFeeRules)` and what namespace is it in?  Might just be me but I can't find anything in MSDN.

Comment: All it's doing there is returning the parameter in JSON format. As for the method, it's inside of a controller class.

Comment: Is this something you wrote?  Could be relevant to the question.  In addition what is 'sent' and what is 'needed' appear to be the same?

Comment: yes, I wrote this. The difference is one is AssignmentFeeRules[0][Currency]:AZN and the other is AssignmentFeeRules[0].Currency:AZN. (Notice the brackets vs the '.')